# How do I take a string and build a working formula

Tags: r, string, formula

I have a data whose names are brought into r as strings.  I need to take those strings and produce a formula that runs.  I've tried to put together some sample data that mimics my actual data.

```
y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
x  = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
weights = c(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,x, weights))

set.seed(1)
glm_control <- glm.control(maxit = 10)
the_weights <- paste(names(df)[3])
the_preds <- paste(names(df)[-1])
the_target <- paste(names(df)[1])
the_form <- as.formula(paste(the_target, " ~ ", the_preds, ",control =", 
glm_control, ",weights =", the_weights, ",family" = quasipoisson(link = 
"log"), data = df))
```

I keep getting an error `Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 1: y ~ x`

Comment: You can't put the non formula stuff in the formula. Things like `control=10` and `weights=weights` need to be passed as separate parameters to whatever function you are calling. Those cannot be in the formula. Also, using `reformulate()` can be cleaner than doing `as.formula(paste())` yourself.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick.  What if those come in as strings though?  How does one formulate the total formula string?

Comment: Parameter names should not be coming in in string form. I mean, if you really need to build code from a string you could `parse()` it, but that's pretty extreme and uncommon. Not sure what problem you are really trying to solve here.

Comment: I'm building an r-based macro in Alteryx.  The user will choose which variables are the predictors and targets via check box and as the workflow runs, the names are brought into their r-connector via strings.  That's the reason why I have to be able to convert strings to a working formula.

Comment: It seems like `glm(as.formula(paste(the_target, " ~ ", the_preds), control = glm_control, weights = df[3], family = quasipoisson(link = "log"), data = df)` would work here.

Comment: Thanks @ Benjamin. This is what I got.
`Error in as.formula(paste(the_target, " ~ ", the_preds), control = glm_control,  : 
  unused arguments (control = glm_control, weights = df[3], family = quasipoisson(link = "log"), data = df)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
y = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
x  = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
weights = c(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,x, weights))

set.seed(1)
glm_control <- eval(parse(text = paste0("glm.control(maxit = "10")")))
the_weights <- paste(names(df)[3])
the_preds <- paste(names(df)[-1])
the_target <- paste(names(df)[1])
the_form <-   paste(the_target,  the_preds, sep = "~"

formula <- eval(parse(text = paste0("glm(","the_form,", weights = "the_weights,", family = quasipoisson(link="log"), data = df)")))
```